# Right shift key not working with " key

Tags: keyboard

I am facing an unusual problem with my laptop's keyboard.

<sub>Please read carefully, as this might sound a little confusing.</sub>

My **<kbd>'</kbd>** (single quote) key seems to be working just fine; my <kbd>right Shift</kbd> key is also (mostly) working.
But when I try to use use the <kbd>right Shift</kbd> key along with **<kbd>'</kbd>** key to produce a `"` (double quote), it doesn't work.

To get a `"`, I have to press <kbd>left Shift</kbd>+**<kbd>'</kbd>**.

All the keys seem to be working just fine except the combination of these two. I don't understand why.

---

**EDIT 1:** When I press <kbd>right Shift</kbd>+**<kbd>'</kbd>** key, nothing appears on the screen. Again nothing happens when I press <kbd>right Shift</kbd>+**<kbd>'</kbd>** twice. Nothing appears on the screen later on.

I am using Windows 7.

This problem didn't occur earlier. One fine morning, my keyboard had stopped working. Just stopped working, I don't know why. So I shut it down. Two hours later, it started working again on its own. The problem has started since then.

**EDIT 2:**  Okay, now another key combination is also not working, i.e. the same problem is occurring with the <kbd>left Shift</kbd> and the **<kbd>+</kbd>** key.

So my

1. <kbd>right Shift</kbd> along with <kbd>'</kbd>
2. <kbd>left Shift</kbd> along with <kbd>+</kbd>

are not working. Can't seem to understand why.

Comment: When you press _shift_ key and _quote_ key, what happens? Nothing appears on the screen or single quote appears (as against double quotes)? If they are next to each other, is it possible that pressing one key is interfering with the press of the other (mechanically or electronically)?

Comment: This is not the dead key issue? What happens if you tyoe right-shift+`'` twice? Or type right-shift+`'` and begin typing text. Does the `"` appear then?

Comment: which os?  Have seen options for treating right shift key differently in some cases.

Comment: @jaychris: Nothing happens when I press shift+quote key. Nothing appears on the screen.

Again nothing happens when I press right-shift+' twice. Nothing appears on the screen later on.

I am using Windows 7.

This problem didn't occur earlier. One fine morning, my keyboard has stopped working. Just stopped working. I shut it down. 2 hrs later, it starts working again on it's own. The problem has started since then.

Comment: You could try installing another language/country and keyboard layout to see if your keyboard layout files became corrupted.

Comment: out of interest,  so these two fail  (rightshift ' fails to give ")  (leftshift = fails to give +).  What about (rightshift = does it give +) and (leftshift ' does it give ")?  Have you tried plugging in a USB Keyboard?  (or different USB keyboard) does that have the exact same problem?  That will also show you whether it's a windows problem or a hardware problem.

Comment: @Piyush: Try removing the keys and clean it up. As I mentioned before, these two keys are close together, may be when right shift is pressed, the quote key is not depressing properly, or some hair or dirt is inside preventing the key press to be registered. Good suggestion by barlop to attach a USB keyboard, that will clear if that is a OS issue.

Comment: @barlop : Yes the rightshift with + works. only the left shift with plus doesn't. I have tried removing the key and cleaned it as well. Haven't had the chance to use a USB keyboard. will update about it as soon as I get to know.

Comment: @Piyush and also (leftshift ' does it give ")?

Comment: @barlop : Yes leftshift ' gives " . But rightshift ' doesn't give me anything. Same thing for rightshift =

Comment: besides or as alternative to  testing with a usb keyboard you could try VNC or remote desktop(mstsc.exe) or teamviewer.

Answer (score 2):

I found something interesting related to this though not exactly the same. And I hope this might be helpful to some one.

I was using a dual boot windows 7 and ubuntu system. One day I found and **Crtl + C** and  **Shift + C** key combination were not working in windows or in linux. But the **right side** **Crtl + C** and  **Shift + C** were working.

How I solved the issue:

- In **ubuntu** I opened **keyboard preferences** >> **Accessibilty**
- Then  under sticky keys **checked** the option *Simulate Simultaneous Keypreses
  -* and **unchecked** the option *disabled sticky keys if two keys are pressed together*

***This solved the problem both in Ubuntu and Windows 7.***

(I do not have privileged to post it as a comment so posted as an answer. Though its not an exact answer, similar things may be tried out to solve such type of issues.)

Answer (score 2):

This happens on windows when your Sticky Keys are off.
turn them on so you can use your *right Shift* key and other keys in combination with other keyboard keys.
to do that: **press the shift key 5 times**

Answer (score 1):

I am on Windows 10. For me, the left shift key has issues. If I press it multiple times in quick succession, I get the alert for Sticky keys - which means the key is working. But it doesn't work in combinations, for e.g. Shift + 9/0 (for parentheses), or Ctrl + Shift + T for reopening a closed tab.

My keyboard has a "Calculator" key in top right and that was stuck for some reason. I pulled it up with a ball pen point and the left shift key started working properly. It has happened twice now.

[image]

Comment: Unbelievable, this is the 7th answer I've tried and seemed silly, yet it worked.  For me it was the "Mail" button that was stuck down on my MS Digital Media Keyboard 3000.  I hadn't even noticed, and I can't understand why having that down would affect how my shift button works, but prying it up fixed it so I can finally type right shift + x and have it work.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i have almost the same problem with you.

but now its solved.
its because there is something under the button, even just some dust can cause this problem.
I suggest to open up the button that you believe its the 'culprit' for your condition its "right shift" clean everything you can under the rubber with anything as long as non-metal thing. clean with care, slowly.
and for testing while cleaning, open browser and go to online keyboard simulator.

hopefully this will help for others.